# blank output on IndriRunQuery in lemur project

Tags: java, nlp, lemur, indri

I'm using lemur for a nlp project, and I indexed some data succesffully
I wanna run a query on index files by IndriRunQuery command
parameter file:

```
    <parameters> 
<index>PATH-TO-INDEX-DIRECTORY</index>
<query> 
    <number>1</number> 
    <text>QUERY SAMPLE STRING</text> 
</query>
<count>50</count></parameters>
```

there is no error, there is no answer. just a blank line in output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer myself
my documents in indexing step weren't in the format that lemur document told
documents told the make training document in this format:

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO>DOCUMENT-ID</DOCNO>
<TEXT>DCOUMENT-PLAIN-TEXT</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

and indexed documents again by: buildIndex [parameterFile]
then user indriRunQuery.exe and worked well